# where is the web folder in Flutter 2?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

As per Flutter Team, the flutter web is already stable in flutter 2 so we dont need to change to beta. However As I need to build and do some modification on flutter web, I cant see where is the web folder when I can change the index.html. Do I need to still go back to beta channel to see that folder? or any thing I should do instead of going back to beta channel. Thanks!

Comment: Are you working on an old project or a new project? What is your current flutter version (flutter doctor)

Comment: Im actually on flutter 2.0.1, and new flutter project to migrate to web

Comment: You should already have the web folder. Can you try running `flutter create .` in your terminal.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for that I should try that

Comment: Important thing.... If you run `flutter create .` in your project's home dir via the terminal... you still might not see the web folder. You might have to restart your IDE ;-)